# How to never have an attribute error for a python object

Tags: python, object, attributes, attributeerror

I would like to define a class that can return something for any attribute requested from it, Is that possible?
e.g

```
class AnyAttr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        <somehow return the attr str for any str>

aa = AnyAttr()
print aa.cat
print aa.dog

Out [1]: 'cat', 'dog'
```

naturally, it should be able to return other things, like looking them up in different dictionaries and returning what it finds or a default value.
Any way this can be done?

Comment: Define `__getattr__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so by implementing the `__getattribute__` method. However, you probably do not want to do this for code that is being used in production ;-)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


class AnyAttr(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attribute):
        return str(attribute)


aa = AnyAttr()
print(aa.cat) # yields 'cat'
print(aa.dog) # yields 'dog'
```